# C# Text-stream access denied

Tags: c#, file-io, authorization, hosts

I guess you know this file well, it's a file for binding some IP to hostnames.

> C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

Notepad can make changes on this file but `C#` `Text-stream` couldn't do anything on it and says `access denied`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

P.S:
My user has enough rights to edit that file because I can edit it with Notepad, but my programm couldn't.

**EDIT:**
One more thing, it doesn't work with users that are created in ActiveDirectory. users who are not from this computer. They're administrator but they are not the owner.

Could it be ownership problem?

Comment: Seems like permission issue. Check what is happening using Process Monitor from SysInternals.

Comment: What OS is this?  On Windows 7 access to the hosts file requires an administrative command prompt.  Is your program running as the same user as the one running notepad?

Comment: @Joe
Windows 7
Yes, the same user.

Comment: @TomasVoracek
Thanks for your advice, yes it must be permission issue but Notepad have modify rights ...

Comment: even run as administrator didn't work!

Comment: @phoog code isn't something, just a textStream

Comment: What type is that, textStream?  Do you mean System.IO.StreamWriter or something else?

Comment: TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add manifest to your programm and request neccessary rights.

Answer (score 1):

UAC???  You need to run your app with elevated privs... also try saving your file you have edited in notepad?  Does that really work?

Comment: @ALi If you are not running notepad with elevated privs you are not really overwriting the file, it could be writing to `%localappdata%\Virtual Store\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` instead of the real file.

Comment: @HenkHolterman He could be using some kind of notepad replacement (like Notepad++ but I think that is visualization aware too) and calling it notepad. I just wanted to cover all the bases

Comment: @ScottChamberlain
Good hint , but I should check it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - No, virtualization only happens with programs that are not Vista/Win7 aware. (reposted due to bad typo)

Comment: P.S: I don't use any notepad replacement.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's my understanding that virtualization only happens with programs that are not Vista/Win7 aware because those programs don't write to the virtualized directories.  Is there more to it?

Comment: A Vista+ program that writs where it shouldn't gets an exception. That includes Notepad.